# Format a date of binding in xaml C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well this is my Label where I want to format my Date:

```
 <Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="110" Height="63"/>
```

The date which is displayed has this format:

```
MM.dd.YYYY
```

And the date I want to get displayed has this format:

```
YYYY-MM-dd
```

Comment: Was any research done? What have you tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @crystal-reports, Is any update?  Please check if my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to format the date as you desired.

```
  <Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"  Content="{Binding Date}" ContentStringFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="63"/>
```

We need to use `ContentStringFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"` to set the label date format correctly.

Result:

[image]